# jira issue collector load asyncrounosly

Tags: jira, issue-tracking

I have set up issue collector on my site placing the code in the head section of my site. problem is when jira crashes or fails it affects my site. how can this be added or loaded without my site being affected if jira is down or unavailable?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://jira.domain.com/s/13a7e22f6b69456f602d8e699958529b-T/en_UKvd67hw/64029/17/1.4.27/_/download/batch/com.atlassian.jira.collector.plugin.jira-issue-collector-plugin:issuecollector/com.atlassian.jira.collector.plugin.jira-issue-collector-plugin:issuecollector.js?locale=en-UK&collectorId=7c2f7815"></script>
```